# DataGridComboBoxColumn selectItem binding issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a ComboBox inside a DataGridand to do selectItem binding but when I write this code ,and I select an item in on ComboBox in the column, all the ComboBox items in the  DataGrid's column are binding and shows the same selected item. I need to bind each ComboBox item with its selectedItem.
I would be happy to get an help.

this is my code:

```
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="CHOOSE" Width="0.7*"  
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=SelectedReceiver,{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">               
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>                      
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.RxList}" />
                        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= Name}" Style="{StaticResource GroupBoxHeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.RxList }" />
                        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= Name}" Style="{StaticResource GroupBoxHeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You bind to `DataGrid.ItemsSource.SomeList` when you actually need to bind to `DataGrid.ItemsSource[x].SomeList`.

Basically your list and selected item will always be the same for each column. You can use a static list for your item-model-class (if the list stays the same) and a property for the `SelectedItem`.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedReceiver}"> <!-- Bind to current item's SelectedReceiver -->
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=(modelNamespace:MyModel.RxList)}"/> <!-- Bind to static list property -->
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```